# Как сделать прокрутку мышью и пальцем на телефоне блока с overflow: scroll или hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой блок с пунктами в одну строку:

```css
.practices_list_wrapper {
  width: 728px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.practices_list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1040px;
}

.practice_item {
  list-style: none;
}

.practice_button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 136px;
    height: 46px;
    border: 2px solid #CEA96C;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #545454;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="practices_list_wrapper">
    <ul class="practices_list">
            <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button current" href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
                <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Как можно сделать прокрутку блока влево/вправо мышью и пальцем на мобильных устройствах? И желательно при этом скрыть саму полосу прокрутки (overflow: hidden).

Перерыл все, не могу найти решения.

Answer (score 0):

Ты пытаешься скроллить practices_list внутри practices_list_wrapper. Это является излишней оберткой, поскольку задачей является добиться возможности скроллить именно карточки. Я перенес стили из practices_list_wrapper в practices_list.

```
<ul class="practices_list">
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button current" href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  <li class="practice_item"><a class="practice_button" href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Для того, чтобы сохранить расстояние между карточками я использовал gap вместо justify-content.

Для того, чтобы скрыть скроллбар я использовал псевдоэлемент скролла в классе practices_list, а также убрал видимость скроллбара в самом классе для других браузеров.

```
.practices_list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  width: 728px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*  Скрываем scrollbal для IE, Edge и Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE и Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

/* Скрываем scrollbar для Chrome, Safari и Opera */
.practices_list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```